# iPhone: Weather report APIs library

Tags: iphone, weather-api

I am planning to add weather report for selected country->state->city, for daily, weekly, monthly averages. I have googled it and also went through couple of discussion on stackoverflow threads and I got confused! Could anyone please tell me if there is already Weather report APIs library available? What could be the best way to implement my requirements? I am just expecting overview so that I don't chose wrong path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [WorldWeatherOnline](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/).

Comment: Thanks Gomathi. Just to mention that I don't want to create a discussion similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis. I am looking for a free library/webservice APIs that provides a data I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled a set of information about different weather APIs looking for a similar solution. My general consensus was the WorldWeatherOnline seemed to be the best bang for the buck (free) and seemed pretty feature rich.

http://michaelwelburn.com/2011/11/02/comparing-weather-apis/

**UPDATE (12/18/2013):** This response was from 2011, since that time some different providers have made updates. I tried to keep the link semi-up to date, but you'll want to take the list provided and do your own research.